# How to set DataGridView's column name and headertext separately from a single SQL statement?

Tags: c#, t-sql, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

When I use SQL statement such as

```
select
    ID as ID,
    Name as CustomerName,
    Day1 as BirthDay,
    Day2 as MemberDay
from [Customer]
```

to populate a `DataGridView` (Named poorly for demonstration purpose),

It will name the columns' Name **AND** HeaderText automatically. (Both ID, CustomerName, BirthDay, and MemberDay)

Is there a way to set the Name and HeaderText differently from the SQL statement itself?

Or I just have to rename each HeaderText individually?

Thank you very much for your help!

**Edit**

Because the SQL statement might be different depend on the user's choice, so it'll be tedious to rename each HeaderText.

Of course it's not impossible to do, but I have to consider all possible situations and handle it accordingly, possible but tiresome and bad practice.

And mostly importantly, it needs to be written back to the database from the `DataGridView` once the user edited the content.

And I can't find the original column name from the `DataGridView` itself, that's why I'm trying to looking for a better way to resolve it.

Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: why do you want to do that? can you please be more clear

Comment: @Shehab Please see the edit.

Comment: Did you check DataPropertyName of a column. I think it has the original field name

Comment: @Shehab Yes, I did. It's all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form of SQL SELECT AS to rename columns in your query results.

So far you’ve seen where queries results return results named after the table columns.

Name the column [Distinct Names].

```
select
    ID as [Customer ID],
    Name as [Customer Name(First and Last)],
    Day1 as [Date of Birth],
    Day2 as [Member Since]
from [Customer]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's "exactly" like the SQL statement I just wrote and didn't solve anything.

Comment: The other option is change HeaderText. You can do it individually or create a Dictionary with a list of SQL Column results and Caption.